# GET method(afnetworking) was cancel on iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, charles-proxy

I tested GET method by using AFNetworking on Charles(Web Debugging tool), however, the connection was canceled immediately.

I tried to get local json ini file by using "Map remote" and "Map local" tool of Charles at the same time.

I doubted ATS(App Transport Security), but I don't know how to clear the problem...

Is there way to clear this problem ?

I tested it on Xcode8.1 and iOS10.0.1.

thank you

Comment: I used "GET" method "https" url.

Answer (score 0):

If you use http resources it can really be ATS. You can easily test it - [try this](http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error), first link for disable ATS, actually, and append here, if it helped.

Comment: Thanks Viad, I know the plist setting, and, I know the setting will be reject next year.

Comment: sure, it's much better to use https, or just add it to exception domains, but for testing its normal :)

Comment: it didn't help?